# How to add billing country to Google Analytics in iOS library

Tags: objective-c, ios, google-analytics

I am tracking a transaction using the GANTracker class from the Google Analytics SDK. I cannot figure out how to get it to set the Billing Country (utmtco). In the JS this seems to be a parameter, but there is nothing like this in the iOS library.

```
- (BOOL)addTransaction:(NSString *)orderID
        totalPrice:(double)totalPrice
         storeName:(NSString *)storeName
          totalTax:(double)totalTax
      shippingCost:(double)shippingCost
         withError:(NSError **)error;
```

This is the closest I get. I have tried to set a custom variable utmtco like so:

```
[[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1 name:@"utmtco" value:@"Country" withError:&error];
```

This does not seem to do anything however, as the call has utmtco as nothing.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're doing up there, but we did it creating a class method. If we need it to return country we just set the country name to a NSString and call [self trackpageView: country];  Hope this help.

```
+(void) trackPageView: (NSString *)pageTracked {

        //Log(@"page view:%@", pageTracked);

        NSError *error;
        if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackPageview: pageTracked
                                             withError:&error]) {
            // Handle error here
            Log(@"Google anaytics track page failed");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi tipsywacky, 

I am making an app for my clients website. Through their website they can track a transaction using the Java Script Google Analytics library with Billing Country set. How do I add this to the addTransaction call I have above.

I do the same thing as you elsewhere for tracking page views etc. But this is needed for tracking actual transactions.

You can see the variable listed here under the GIF request headers https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/concepts/gaConceptsTrackingOverview